# Calling a function using a Funcptr which is a menber of struct in python

Tags: python, function-pointers

I have a struct as below:

```
class Exprs(Structure):
  _fields_ = [("func",POINTER(CMPFUNC)),
           other members]

CMPFUNC= CFUNCTYPE(ExprArg, POINTER(Exprs), ExprArgList,c_int)// Prototype
```

e is of type POINTER(Exprs)

When I try to call `e.contents.func(e, eArgList,0)` ,I get an error

> LP_CfunctionType object is not callable

I have used appropriate ctypes casting. Please help me solve this error

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for function prototype types takes an address directly. You probably just need to drop the `POINTER` specifier in the structure definition. What you have written is equivalent to:

```
struct Exprs {
    ExprArg (**func)(Exprs *, ExprArgList, int);
};
```

If that's really what you wanted then use `e.contents.func.contents(e, eArgList,0)`